# Formatação de data está trocando seus parâmetros

Tags: php, cakephp

Estou usando `callback beforeSave` para formatar a data de `d/m/Y` para `Y-m-d`. A data está sendo salva como `Y-d-m` ao invés de `Y-m-d`. Sintaticamente o código está certo.

A data está na tabela como date.

função beforeSaveData

Observem que eu debugo `$data` antes da formatação e depois da formatação. Antes da formatação, a data está correta, depois da formatação, o mês assume o valor do dia e o valor do dia assume o mês. Ex: 10/01/2016, fica como: 2016-10-01, ou seja, fica primeiro de outubro.

AppModel:

```
public function beforeSaveData($data) {
    debug($data);
    $data = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($data));
    debug($data); die();
    return $data;$data;
}
```

Model Despesa:

```
public function beforeSave($options=>array()) {
    $this->data['Despesa']['valor_despesa'] = $this->beforeSaveValor($this->data['Despesa']['valor_despesa']);

    $this->data['Despesa']['data_despesa'] = $this->beforeSaveData($this->data['Despesa']['data_despesa']);
    return true;
}
```

No controller:

```
public function inserirDespesa() {
    if ($this->request->isPost()) {

        if ($this->Despesa->save($this->request->data)) {

            $this->Session->setFlash("Despesa inserida");
        }

        else {
            $this->Session->setFlash("Despesa não inserida");
        }
    }
}
```

E segue também a view. A data na view está como `type=text` porque tenho as funções regulares em `javascript` para data e valor monetário.

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
echo $this->element('menuDespesas');

//echo $this->Html->script('inserir_despesa');
?>

<script>

function mascara(o, f) {
obj=o;
fun=f;
setTimeout("execMascara()", 1);
}

function execMascara() {
obj.value=fun(obj.value);
}

function data(data) {
data=data.replace(/\D/g,""); // Remove tudo o que não é dígito//
data=data.replace(/^(\d{2})(\d)/,"$1/$2"); // Coloca barra entre o 2° e o 3°
                                            // digito//
data=data.replace(/(\d{2})(\d)/,"$1/$2"); // Coloca barra entre o 4° e o 5°
                                            // dígito//
return data;
}

function valor(valor){
valor=valor.replace(/\D/g,"");
valor=valor.replace(/(\d)(\d{2})$/,"$1,$2");
return valor;
}

</script>

<h2>INSERIR DESPESA</h2><p>

<?php
echo $this->Session->flash();

echo $this->Form->create('Despesa');

echo $this->Form->input('despesa', array('label'=>'Despesa:', 'maxlength'=>'30'));

//campo valor_despesa do tipo texto para aceitar a "," (vírgula).

echo $this->Form->input('valor_despesa', array('label'=>'Valor (apenas números, incluindo os centavos. Coloque 00 quando não houver centavos):', 'maxlength'=>'10', 'type'=>'text', 'onkeypress'=>"mascara(this, valor)"));

//data_despesa com type=text para possibilitar a digitação e o símbolo de "/".
echo $this->Form->input('data_despesa', array('label'=>'Data:', 'type'=>'text', 'maxlength'=>'10', 'onkeypress'=>"mascara(this, data)" ));

echo $this->Form->input('local_despesa', array('label'=>'Local da despesa', 'maxlength'=>'15'));

echo "<p>";
echo $this->Form->submit('Inserir despesa');
echo $this->Form->button('Limpar', array('type'=>'reset'));
echo $this->Form->end();

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Já tentou fazer o beforeSaveData manual com explodes?

Comment: Disponibilize o seu código diretamente na pergunta, não em um serviço externo. Se o mesmo sair do ar, não termos como visualizar.

Comment: @Guilherme Lopes Não pensei nisso! Vou fazer aqui.

Comment: !CelsomTrindade prefiro por no hastebin ou no pastebin que evita os problemas de edição aqui no stack e é mais fácio de por o código, além da pergunta não ficar extensa.

Comment: Para não ficar tão extensa a pergunta, coloque apenas os trechos importantes da dúvida, as vezes muitas empresas bloqueiam sites externos ai acaba complicando para quem quer ajudar pois o site pode estar bloqueado ou fora do ar como o @Celsom disse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a classe [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) para fazer a formatação:

```
$data = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $data);
return $data->format('Y-m-d')
```

Comment: também funcionou. Optei pela Date::create.

Answer (score 3):

Segue uma implementação para data que possivelmente irá resolver seu problema:

```
public function beforeSaveData($data)
{
   $data = explode("/", $data);
   $novaData = $data[2] . "-" . $data[1] . "-" . $data[0];
   return $novaData;    
}
```

segue exemplo do código: https://ideone.com/P4NwPB

Comment: !André Nascimento ok, funcionou! Não havia pensado no explode!